# Using dlopen to load one .so in Python says it can't find another in the same directory

Tags: python, dlopen

I connected yesterday using the SSH protocol to another computer and tried to load, through Python, a SO file (which would be compiled C). Here is what I got in the CLI:
[image]

The file that is being requested (`libLMR_Demodulator.so`) next to "OSError:" is in the same dir as the file I want to load (`libDemodulatorJNI_LMR.so`).

The python code (v3.5.2) is the following one:

```
import ctypes
sh_obj = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libDemodulatorJNI_LMR.so')
actual_start_frequency = sh_obj.getActualStartFrequency(ctypes.c_long(0))
print('The Current Actual Frequency Is: ' + str(actual_start_frequency))
```

Comment: I would like to know why I am getting this error... Does anyone has an idea ???...

Comment: Is the `./libLMR_Demodulator.so` in the same directory that you're currently in when you run your Python script? That's where you're asking it to look.

Comment: Set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to include the directory where dependencies will be found.

Comment: @lurker, the one it couldn't find isn't the same as the one they named in their code; the path applies only to the originally named file. I've edited the title to be more clear about that, since the question originally didn't call it out very explicitly.

Comment: @AgustnErnestoCardeilhacBans, ...btw, adding a `c` tag for a question that someone having only knowledge of C can't answer is liable to pull in a bunch of very grumpy people (unhappy about seeing questions they aren't interested in make it through their filters). Yes, your shared object was compiled from C source, but that doesn't make it a C question unless you're asking how to change the shared object itself. The SSH tag was even less defensible (unless, say, you proved that the problem *only* happens when you connect to the host over ssh).

Comment: @Rawing, eh? The current working directory is *not* in the default library search path. The OP named that directory for the library they're ultimately trying to load, but it's not the library they're trying to load that wasn't found, but rather one of its dependencies. (If `.` *were* part of the default library path, you'd have much the same security bugs you have when it's in the `PATH` for executables).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oops, you're absolutely right. I should've taken a closer look at the error message.

Comment: lurker: Thankx for your time !.
Charles Duffy: I'll be testing that right now ! thankx a bunch

Comment: I ran again the script trying to load another SO file (I messed on that one) and now it's asking me the following OS file (I set the environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH"):
libg3verify.so
This one I searched it everywhere but wasnt successful in finding it. What could be ?...

Comment: @AgustnErnestoCardeilhacBans, *shrug* -- asking us where to find a copy of a given library falls into #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: If you read more in detail, I didnt request or ask for anything but asked what could it be...

Answer (score 5):

@Charles Duffy is right. The issue come from dependencies. You can verify this by command:

```
ldd libLMR_Demodulator.so
```

You have several ways to fix this issue:

- Put all the lib to `/lib`, `/usr/lib` paths, or directly install them to your system.
- Put the libs' path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` file, then run `ldconfig` to refresh cache.
- use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to add the libs' path, then try to run you script

  ```
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[..path] python [script.py]
  ```

or

```
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=[..path]
    python [script.py]
```

You can check with manual of `dlopen` to get more details.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is the dependencies that are problematic, there might be yet another remedy: load the *dependencies* explicitly. Because `libLMR_Demodulator.so` was not found with RPATH, it might be enough to just load it manually first:

```
import ctypes

lib_demodulator = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libLMR_Demodulator.so')
sh_obj = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libDemodulatorJNI_LMR.so')
actual_start_frequency = sh_obj.getActualStartFrequency(ctypes.c_long(0))
print('The Current Actual Frequency Is: ' + str(actual_start_frequency))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got here looking for how to ensure that a module / package with a .so file was able to load another .so file that it depends upon -- changing the current directory to the location of the first .so file (i.e., in the directory where the module is) seems to work for me:

```
import os,sys,inspect
cwd = os.getcwd()
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
os.chdir(currentdir)
import _myotherlib
os.chdir(cwd) # go back
```

might also work for the OP case?